# ¿Como validar un input en javascript?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objeto

Lo que quiero hacer es validar un input si tiene contenido o no para agregarle o no una clase a un elemento label1 en html.

```
emailbox.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    if (label1.classList.contains('active')){
        label1.classList.remove('active');
}else{
        label1.classList.add('active');
    }
})

emailbox.addEventListener('blur', ()=>{
   
    label1.classList.remove('active');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

No necesitas usar JS, puedes simplemente usar CSS y HTML, para esto debes colocar el atributo `required` en el `input` y aplicar las reglas correspondientes usando el pseudo selector `:invalid`

Aquí un ejemplo

```css
input + label{
  display:none;
  color:red
}

input:invalid + label{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<form>
 <input required>
 <label>Correo Requerido</label>
 
 <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
</form>
```

Ahora para responder tu pregunta, el código debería ser algo como:

```js
emailbox.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
   if(inputAvalidar.value){ //valido si tiene contenido
     label1.classList.remove('active'); //si lo tiene saco clase
   }
   else{ //si no tiene, agrego clase
        label1.classList.add('active');
    }
})
```

```css
.active{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<form>
   <input id="inputAvalidar" placeholder="Correo" required>
   <label id="label1">Correo Requerido</label>

   <input type="button" value="Valida" id="emailbox">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Una mejor forma de hacerlo sería capturar a tus elementos, que vendrían a ser:

- Tu input del correo electrónico para las validaciones.
- Un label que servirá para indicar si es requerido o no.

---

Y podemos hacer lo siguiente:

```js
const emailbox = document.getElementById('emailbox'); // capturo al input.
const label = document.getElementById('label1'); // capturo al label.

// cuando escribimos en tu input "emailbox", escuchamos el evento "input"...
emailbox.addEventListener('input', () => {
  // y verificamos si está vacío el input "emailbox"...
  if (emailbox.value.trim() === '') {
    label.style.color = 'red'; // si cumple, pintamos el label a rojo.
  } else {
    label.style.color = 'black'; // de lo contrario, pintamos el label a negro.
  }
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="emailbox" id="label1">Correo electrónico:</label>
  <input type="text" id="emailbox">
  <button id="submit" type="submit">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

Otra versión más segura sería poder enviar el formulario si el campo está lleno, de lo contrario deshabilitamos el botón de enviar:

```js
const emailbox = document.getElementById('emailbox'); // capturo al input.
const label = document.getElementById('label1'); // capturo al label.
const submit = document.getElementById('submit'); // capturo al botón de enviar.

submit.setAttribute('disabled', true); // deshabilitamos el botón de enviar por defecto.

// cuando escribimos en tu input "emailbox", escuchamos el evento "input"...
emailbox.addEventListener('input', () => {
  // y verificamos si está vacío el input "emailbox"...
  if (emailbox.value.trim() === '') {
    label.style.color = 'red'; // si cumple, pintamos el label a rojo.
    submit.setAttribute('disabled', false); // y el botón de enviar permanecerá deshabilitado.
  } else {
    label.style.color = 'black'; // de lo contrario, pintamos el label a negro.
    submit.removeAttribute('disabled'); // y el botón de enviar se habilitará.
  }
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="emailbox" id="label1">Correo electrónico:</label>
  <input type="text" id="emailbox">
  <button id="submit" type="submit">Enviar</button>
</form>
```